# Folder permissions with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have some folders in my proyect root, for example:

```
- admin
- img
```

In the root I also have an index.php.

In .htaccess, following is written

```
RewriteRule (.*)/?$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

If I want to access img folder I should add before

```
RewriteRule img/(.*)$ img/$1 [L]
```

But the problem is when I enter in admin, automatically my URL rewrites to "admin/" when I dont wan't the last backslash "/", just "admin"

There is another way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add the following to your rule

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Meaning only rewrite if the file or directory doesn't  exist.